The Golden Section of a Square question
Does anyone know where the numbers 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 are measured from in the following picture?
I understand the top right is the Golden Rectangle.

ref:
Modular Book Site

Segment $2$ joins mdpts of the top and bottom sides of the square. (If the square has side-length $s$, then seg $3$ has length $\frac12s\sqrt{5}$, so that after drawing the arc to $4$, the extended base has length $\frac12s(1+\sqrt{5})=s\phi$.) Segment $5$ is the diagonal of the original square, and the arc to $6$ extends the base "the other way". Segs $7$ and $8$ join the ends of the extensions to the mdpt of the top of the original square, creating an angle of about $90.6^\circ$. (The text suggests that the goal is a right angle, and that this is someone's approximate construction.)

The dogmatic approach of Le Corbusier's "modulor" has been the bible of many architects in the 1950s, but, as all theories not well "grounded", you have to take his writings with "circonspection"...

Fig 10 of the doc (pg 40) shows the elements put together. ... It should be noted that there's a bit of nonsense in the accompanying text. It says the "Maillard diagram", which constructs a true rt angle to seg $7$ at the top mdpt, constructs an alternative extension pt "i" that determines a rectangle equal to two "contiguous squares equal to the initial square". In fact, the ratio of the rectangle's base to the square's side is about $2.012$. ... I don't understand: If they want to find a rt angle within two "contiguous squares", why not simply build the squares and draw appropriate diags?

@Blue Thanks.  You solved it for me.  The numbers are "labeling" the segments, not an actual length of line.
